# MBR to GPT; 25GB Factory Recovery partition for windows; ASUS laptop

Tags: windows, mbr, gpt, recovery-partition

I have an ASUS laptop with a 25GB factory recovery partition of 64bit windows on MBR disk drive. Since this partition contains the image of windows 64bit which should support UEFI and GPT, will I be able to use this partition  for factory recovery if I convert my drive from MBR to GPT?

Comment: Yes, The image just reinstalls Windows

Comment: When you use [`Mbr2Gpt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt), it applies the correct GPT GUIDs to each partition, and the EFI boot and WinRE partitions have different GUIDs than basic data partitions like the OS partition. Normally OEM recovery images don't reinstall Windows, they format the OS partition, then apply the WIM image that was captured at the factory via `Dism` _(it's often in 4GB split-WIMs [`.swm`])_

Comment: I am not going to use mbr2gpt command, since it is windws 7 which does not support this feature. I will have to use 3 party, maybe easus.